# How to protect decryption key from decompilation?

Tags: java, security, reverse-engineering, encryption, drm

I'm a beginner java programmer. I'm working on an application that decrypts some data.
The decryption key is hardcoded into the software and thus can be seen by analyzing the bytecode.

I know that reverse engineering cannot be prevented entirely so what I'm trying to do is to make the process as hard as possible.

My idea is not to directly put the key into my code but have it go through some kind of transformation.
For example, I could write -

```
private static final byte[] HC256A = Hex
            .decode("8589075b0df3f6d82fc0c5425179b6a6"
                    + "3465f053f2891f808b24744e18480b72"
                    + "ec2792cdbf4dcfeb7769bf8dfa14aee4"
                    + "7b4c50e8eaf3a9c8f506016c81697e32");
```

This way someone looking at the bytecode can't read it straight away. But will have to follow the logic and apply transformations to it, which won't be that much easier at byte level.

So what do you guys think? Is this useful? What could be the be the best transformation other than hex decoding?
Are there any other methods available to protect hardcoded decryption keys?

Thanks for all your suggestions.

Comment: You could listen for a debugger connecting (works in C++, not sure how to do that in Java), and if so, delete the value from memory.

Comment: What is the sensitivity of the data being decoded? This will help serve as a guide as to how much effort to put into protecting that data. Any form of hiding the key in the bytecode is relatively easy to defeat. Additionally this would require that every user of the software has the same key and recompilation is required to change to key.

Comment: The data is quite sensitive. It is a digital media print which if leaked would cause serious problems for the company.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right way to attack such obfuscation (especially in bytecode languages) is to attach debugger to the place to which the key is passed (if debugging is not possible, start analyzing code from that place). This way the attacker doesn't need to look for the key at all and he doesn't care how obfuscated the key is. So you need to re-think your design.

If you only want to protect from the amateur lurkers, then splitting the key and XORing it's parts (possibly with different keys), would be enough. One more trick - derive the key from text constants already present in the code (such as application name). This makes the key less obvious than splitting or XORing.

Comment: +1 for answering **both** why you shouldn't do it **and** how to do it ;-)

Comment: @Joachim actually the two parts cover differents set of attackers :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't code the key into the source code at all. Keep it separate, ship it separately, e.g. in a Java keystore, and only to customers/sites/clients you trust, and put some legalese in the licence that places the onus on them if they leak the keystore.

Answer (score 0):

Faced with a similar problem (in c) I went with single use XOR pads.  This is good because it looks like garbage... if you get really clever you can snoop for that (incorrect) key in use.  I would avoid anything that injects human readable strings as those will invariably draw attention to that bit of code.

Comment: XOR pads with some bit-shifting applied is probably as good as it gets: it's not really *good* prevention, but it foils those who simply call `javah` and hope to get a direct dump of the key.